# Introducing builder for existing projects

Tags: eclipse

In next release of our product we are adding builders. This change will be okay for newly created projects, but existing projects don't have builders defined in .project file, thus builders do not work for these projects.

One way of solving this is to examine each project's .project file and see if builder entry exists, if not - add it. Is there a better way to do this, as it sounds like a pretty common issue that might arise in Eclipse application where a new builder is introduced one application is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way then manually adding it. Maybe you could add a new command in the project navigator that adds the builders manually; or when opening a file with your editor, it could check for the builder.

Comment: Thanks. I created a workspace listener that is triggered when resource is added. During that time I check project description to see what builders are missing and add then at that time.